# after_create action in model is not updating an attribute of the parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have  *Post* and *Comment* model.

I want to achieve the following: Each time a post is created or commented the `:content_changed_at` attribute of the post should update with `created_at`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_names, :content_changed_at

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  def init_sort_column
    self.content_changed_at = self.created_at || Time.now
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true

  after_create :update_parent_sort_column

  private

  def update_parent_sort_column
    if self.post
      self.post.content_changed_at = self.created_at
    end
  end
end
```

`content_changed_at` is updating when the post is created (with its initial `created_at` date). But for some reason, the attribute is not updating when a post is commented.

This is how a post comment is created:

comments_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    comment_attr = params[:comment].merge :user_id => current_user.id
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_attr)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

The generated SQL when you create a post:

```
#<Post id: 64, title: "tttttttttest", content: "hello", user_id: nil, created_at: "2012-03-12 10:07:29", updated_at: "2012-03-12 10:07:29", comments_count: 0, total_votes: 0, content_changed_at: "2012-03-12 10:07:29">
```

Every is working fine for now: `content_changed_at: "2012-03-12 10:07:29`

The generated SQL when you create a comment for a post:

```
(0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("content", "created_at", "post_id", "total_votes", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "teststsetsetset"], ["created_at", Mon, 12 Mar 2012 10:10:09 UTC +00:00], ["post_id", 64], ["total_votes", 0], ["updated_at", Mon, 12 Mar 2012 10:10:09 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil]]
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 64 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "comments_count" = COALESCE("comments_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "posts"."id" = 64
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => #<Comment id: 51, content: "teststsetsetset", post_id: 64, user_id: nil, created_at: "2012-03-12 10:10:09", updated_at: "2012-03-12 10:10:09", total_votes: 0>
```

now if I check the post again:

```
content_changed_at: "2012-03-12 10:07:29
```

The date is the same.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: You appear to be updating the post's attribute but then not saving the post.  What happens if you call `self.post.save` as a second line in your callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `update_parent_sort_column` method, you have changed the `content_changed_at` of the post, but you have NOT actually saved it. Try doing this.

```
def update_parent_sort_column
    if self.post
      self.post.content_changed_at = self.created_at
      self.post.save
    end
  end
```

Or use [update_attribute](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000400) method to change only one column of the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

    def update_parent_sort_column
      if post
        self.post.content_changed_at = self.created_at
      end
    end
  end
```

in this method, you forgot `self.post.save` to apply changes.

you can also try [update_column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column), if you want to skip callbacks in Post model.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  private
  def update_parent_sort_column
    if post
      self.post.update_column(:content_changed_at, self.created_at)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @evfwcqcg Damn, now which answer should I tick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following in your Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :content, :user_id

belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true, :touch => :content_changed_at
...
```

`touch` will update the `content_changed_at` of the associated `Post` model field when `Comment` is saved or destroyed